# How do I prevent Visual Studio Code from automatically deleting whitespace in blank lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I move the cursor from a line without typing anything on it, VS Code seems to automatically delete the whitespace from that line so that, when I put the cursor back on that line, it ends up flush to the left, forcing me to tab to the desired indentation level again. What setting do I change to make it not do that? I tried Googling this problem but all the answers were about removing blank lines with regular expressions, which is not my issue at all.

Comment: "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false

Comment: I responded to a similar answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968474/vscode-keeping-indents-on-empty-lines/70947049#70947049

Answer (score -2):

/* Automatically remove indentation in empty lines on save */
"emptyIndent.removeIndent": true,

Comment: Is that an  extenstion that provides that setting?  `emptyIndent.removeIndent`?  It isn't built-in.

Comment: Looks like this is from this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DmitryDorofeev.empty-indent