# VS Code - How to stop it deleting whitespaces?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft's VS Code to edit css, html and ts files that are shared by my team on a VSTS Git repo. However, my VS Code keeps removing empty/whitespaces that my colleagues added when I save any change (Image below) and this screws up the whole Git Diff part, as almost every single line of code shows as a diff.
I tried to disable every single config setup but nothings works:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968474/vscode-keeping-indents-on-empty-lines

Answer (score 19):

At the end, what was causing my problem was the extension: **EditorConfig for VS Code**

> This plugin attempts to override user/workspace settings with settings
> found in .editorconfig files. No additional or vscode-specific files
> are required. As with any EditorConfig plugin, if root=true is not
> specified, EditorConfig will continue to look for an .editorconfig
> file outside of the project.

I believe, it was overriding the options I selected inside of VS Code (such as *files.trimTrailingWhitespace: false*). So, no setup change I was making was actually being applied.

Comment: god bless you! I was going crazy with this kind of changes that appeared after that I installed this extension (along with other ones) but I was unable to relate the problem with this extension directly until now!

Comment: Maybe it could help other people, for me it was the "empty-indent" extension

Answer (score 8):

It seems you have trailing whitespace enabled in **User Preferences** too.

I'd suggest opening your configuration file of VSCode using
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or
<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in Mac and then go to **Open User Settings**.

I'm sure the next line is around there somewhere, delete it or change it to `false`.

```json
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
```

Comment: Thank you Lucas. Actually, it was already changed to false. It still was not working. However, I went around the problem by disabling all my extensions. It seems like it was the extension: EditorConfig for VS Code.

Comment: This is a good option, which I do not want to disable. Is there a way to do not trim whitespaces only for .diff files?

Comment: @EugenKonkov since my comment above, VSCode added language specific settings: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings
For example: 
"[.diff]": { "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true }

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) extension from lonefy
caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Editor › Comments: Ignore Empty Lines
——>choose ：false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).