# Can VSCode stay at the same column position after pressing arrow keys?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode to write all my PHP, and I could swear it used to behave this way by default: When I press `<ENTER>` or arrow-up or arrow-down, I want the cursor to align intelligently; meaning: I want the cursor to be at the correct indent position depending on context. So, after I press ENTER after a line of code with an `IF` statement, it should indent 1 tab position (relative to the `IF` line) after pressing ENTER. It does do this.

But if I press ENTER a few times and then press `<UP-ARROW>`, the cursor goes to column position 1 at the beginning of the line. This is so annoying. I want the cursor position to remain at the logical tab-stop position when I arrow up and down. If I want to go to the beginning of the line for some reason, I can press `<HOME>`.

I think one of my settings got tweaked, and now it doesn't behave this way. How I want it is also how NPP behaves by default.

Here is one example:

1. My cursor is at the end of a line of code with an IF block.
2. I press enter and the cursor snaps to 1 tabstop in, as expected.
3. I press enter a few more times, and the cursor remains at 1 tabstop in, as expected.
4. I press `<UP-ARROW>` and the cursor snaps to position 1 at the beginning of the previous line. WHY??

I want to be able to arrow-up and arrow-down, and the cursor remains at the correct tab position (whether that be 1 tabstop in, 2, 3, 4...etc), just like when pressing ENTER.

Is there a setting that does this?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate, I just couldn't find it before. Problem solved!

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling this setting:

```
Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace
Remove trailing auto inserted whitespace.
```

Disabling it solves that issue for me (in js/ts files at least).

Comment: if so, then why not close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47968474/11107541 ?

Comment: Hallelujah! Thanks for the tip.